# Callback before RequireJS "define" function is called?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm new to Backbone, and i'm helping to maintain an app that has lots of Backbone and RequireJS code that does something like so:

```
define(

    ['backbone', 'underscore'],

    function(Backbone, _) {
      // some code here
    }
);
```

I'd like to configure Underscore in each of these pages... In the most simple sense, I could just do something like so:

```
define(

    ['backbone', 'underscore'],

    function(Backbone, _) {

      // do some stuff to configure underscore
      configureUnderscore(_);

    }
);
```

but I'd like to leave each page's `define` function alone, and just inject a callback that's called before the `define` callback is called.

How can this be done with Backbone or RequireJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to make this work as suggested in [another answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22201343/26510), and copied from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395869/26510) to a similar question:

### main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'underscore': 'underscoreConfig',
        'originalUnderscore': 'underscore'
    },
    shim: {
        'originalUnderscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

### underscoreConfig.js

```
define(['originalUnderscore'], function(_) {
    _.templateSettings =
    {
        evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
        interpolate : /<%cleanHtml([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
        escape      : /<%[=-]([\s\S]+?)%>/g
    };
    return _;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would probably to define a requireJS module named (e.g.) `rawUnderscore` which returns Undercore without any configuration.

Then, create a new module named `underscore`which requires `rawUnderscore` and configures it before returning its value.

Comment: Hmmm... This sounds really close. After thinking about it a bit more I think my "configure underscore" example was a bit too simple. I'd like to be able to configure all the loaded modules in one place. So if I had 10 modules that were loaded, then I'd like to go and configure them all at once. I know I could do this if I added my 'configureModules' module to the end of the require list, but I'd prefer not to have to do that. I'll edit the question and add this as a note.

Comment: For my purposes, this is close enough! Thanks for the answer. I've added some detail on how I actually got it to work to the question above, but since this is what got me moving in the right direction, this is marked as the answer... Thanks!

Comment: A way to do this as described can be found at [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395869/26510)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (completely untested) may be to define a "require" variable before require.js is included, as [detailed here in the Require.JS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), and [here as well](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps)

```
<script>
    var require = {
        deps: ["some/module1", "my/module2", "a.js", "b.js"],
        callback: function(module1, module2) {
            //This function will be called when all the dependencies
            //listed above in deps are loaded. Note that this
            //function could be called before the page is loaded.
            //This callback is optional.
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```