# RequireJS - How to configure Underscore before it's loaded by Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, amd

I'd like to know how to load Underscore and Backbone using RequireJS and be able to configure Underscore before it's passed to Backbone.

I've seen [this popular question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131265/loading-backbone-and-underscore-using-requirejs) about this similar topic, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get Underscore to be configured for both of the following situations:

- Underscore is required by itself
- Underscore is loaded by Backbone

So my question is the following:

## How can I configure Underscore using RequireJS when required by itself, and when required with Backbone in a module?

Here's what I've tried:

### Approach that should work, but DOESN'T:

My first idea ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22201343/26510)) was to define a requireJS module named (e.g.) rawUnderscore which returns Underscore without any configuration. Then, create a new module named underscore which requires rawUnderscore and configures it before returning its value. This causes loading problems (couldn't load backbone)

#### Configure Require.js modules

```
// When you initially setup require.js, add a new module to configure underscore
// Make it a dependency of backbone, so it'll always be loaded whenever 
// backbone is used.
require.config({
    paths: {
        'underscore': 'underscoreConfig',
        'rawUnderscore': 'underscoreOriginal'
    },
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            deps: ['rawUnderscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        }
    }
});
```

#### underscoreConfig.js

```
define(['rawUnderscore'], function (_) {
    'use strict';

    _.templateSettings = 
    {
        evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
        interpolate : /<%cleanHtml([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
        escape      : /<%[=-]([\s\S]+?)%>/g
    };
       
    return _;
});
```

### Approach that works - Edit Underscore and remove AMD ability:

This works if I remove the AMD lines from Underscore.js (ie force Underscore to not be AMD compliant). I'd prefer not to do this as I like to keep libraries as they are, to ease future maintenance.

#### Configure Require.js to use the underscore patch

```
  require.config({
          shim: {
          underscore: {
            deps: ['underscorePatch'],
              exports: '_',
              init: function(patchIt){
                  return patchIt(this._);
              }
          }
      }
  });
```

#### underscorePatch.js

```
  define('underscorePatch', [], function(){
      'use strict';

      function patch(_){
          _.templateSettings = {
              evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
              interpolate : /<%cleanHtml([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
              escape      : /<%[=-]([\s\S]+?)%>/g
          };
          return _;
      }

      return patch;
  });
```

### Approach that works when loaded with Backbone:

This approach works, but only in the context of when Backbone being loaded as well. Not when Underscore is required by itself.

#### Configure Require.js modules

```
// When you initially setup require.js, add a new module to configure underscore
// Make it a dependency of backbone, so it'll always be loaded whenever 
// backbone is used.
require.config({
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscoreConfig', 'underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        }
    }
});
```

#### underscoreConfig.js

```
define(['underscore'], function (_) {
    'use strict';

    _.templateSettings = 
    {
       evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
       interpolate : /<%cleanHtml([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
       escape      : /<%[=-]([\s\S]+?)%>/g
    };
       
    return _;
});
```

Comment: Just wondering.  Why does underscore need to be configured before it is passed to backbone?  Does the config not work otherwise?

Comment: yeah - that was the problem. If it wasn't done this way, then backbone got it before it was configured.

Comment: Fair enough - it seems to work for me even if I apply the settings after backbone is loaded, but perhaps our use cases are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first example was on the right track.  The following seems to work:

### main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'underscore': 'underscoreConfig',
        'originalUnderscore': 'underscore'
    },
    shim: {
        'originalUnderscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

### underscoreConfig.js

```
define(['originalUnderscore'], function(_) {
    _.templateSettings =
    {
        evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
        interpolate : /<%cleanHtml([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
        escape      : /<%[=-]([\s\S]+?)%>/g
    };
    return _;
});
```